# I upgraded the android studio to 3.0 ,load product error

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Comment: Use the _exactly_  the same version for all support libs. I.e use 26.0.2

Comment: show your gradle app file

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: this is not duplicated at all of the linked question, why is marked as one?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this . Go to your project directory and delete gradle folder . now restart android studio and sync gradle again . i hope this'll help you